# Get difference of two json strings by ignoring specific field

Tags: java, json, jackson, compare

I am working on comparing two JSON strings and getting the difference if not the same. Here I want to ignore a few fields while comparing.
Will Jackson provide this facility or any other library is better?

> Json1:

```
{
    "name": "something",
    "id": "1",
    "version": "123"
}
```

> Json2:

```
{
    "name": "nothing",
    "id": "1",
    "version": "12356"
}
```

I am using the below code to find the difference between the above sample json strings

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode node1 = mapper.valueToTree(json1);
JsonNode node2 = mapper.valueToTree(json2);
String diff = JsonDiff.asJson(node1, node2).toString();
logger.info("Difference: " + diff);
```

But I want to ignore *version* while comparing the JSON from the above sample JSON.

Can *Jackson* do this or any other better library available?

Comment: Jackson can compare json with its equal method and it takes a custom comparator:
[docs](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#equals-java.util.Comparator-com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode-)

Comment: @JonathanAndersson, yes but I want the difference by ignoring specific fields.

Comment: What will the diff string look like? Is it still formatted as JSON? If so I would create an Java object with the fields you are interested in, in this case, "id" and "name" and deserialize it to that class, and then to get the diff as a string, I would once again serialize it, then you will have your diff as a string. Might not be the fastest way but easy to code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am successfully able to achieve it by using different libs :

> Imports

```
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
    import com.flipkart.zjsonpatch.JsonDiff;
    import com.jayway.jsonpath.DocumentContext;
    import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;
```

> Code snippet

```
DocumentContext existingDoc = JsonPath.parse(json1);
DocumentContext incomingDoc = JsonPath.parse(json2);

existingDoc.delete("version");
incomingDoc.delete("version");

JsonNode existingNode = mapper.readTree(existingDoc.jsonString());
JsonNode incomingNode = mapper.readTree(incomingDoc.jsonString());

String diffs = JsonDiff.asJson(existingNode, incomingNode).toString();

logger.info("Difference: " + diffs);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need off-the-shelf implementation, then you can refer to:
https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-patch

Otherwise, if the requirement is on simple nested objects and you want to ignore properties during comparison  you can implement ObjectMapper and override the equals method.
To Remove a file from comparison you can do:

```
((ObjectNode)node1).remove("version");
((ObjectNode)node2).remove("version");
```

Then you can simply call your JsonDiff to analyze.

Comment: the above link doesn't say anything about skip specific fields